# Differential and single-ended input impedance

Tags: impedance

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIMOD.jpg) circuit and I'm interested in finding both the single-ended and differential input impedance. But is there even a difference? This is also at DC, so we can just ignore the inductors and the cap and assume them as ideal. The single ended impedance was easy enough, it was approximately 5k. But what's the differential input impedance?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unusual to hear single-ended and differential. Are you sure you don't mean common-mode and differential?

Differential is measured from one input to the other input. (It's what a signal sees if it flows into one input and out the other input).

Common mode is measured by shorting the two inputs together and measuring between that node and ground. (It's what a signal sees when it appears on both inputs).

Single ended would mean between one input and GND, but that is a meaningless measurement for this kind of circuit since you don't send a signal into this circuit that way.

Comment: ... No I mean single-ended and differential. So is the differential input impedance just 215 ohms?

Comment: @kefffin About 215 Ohms. Or more specifically, 215||20K. Single ended would mean between one input and GND, but that is a meaningless measurement for this kind of circuit since you don't send a signal into this circuit that way.

Comment: hmm I wouldn't say its meaningless. 215||20K, really? I wouldn't think the 10k's matter. No current would flow from input to another through those, it would go ground. I see that as an open essentially.

Comment: @kefffin Not in a differential signal. Apply 1V to one input and -1V to the other input. Where does the current go?

Comment: I guess each source will have current flowing through its corresponding 10k...but still not seeing it

Comment: Current would flow from +1V into GND. But current would also flow from  GND to -1V. The two currents flowing in ground cancel each other out and the current effectively flows from +1V to -1V. The point is that a source driving the differential signals effectively has to drive 215||20K, not 215.

Comment: hmmm....thanks for your help btw. I'm still not making that last connection in my brain. current effectively flows from +1 to -1V?

Comment: oh wait, I guess that's basically the same as having a resistor there. I think I see it now

Comment: fuck I'm not sure actually lol

Comment: Oh I miss your latest comment. I see what you're saying. Thanks

Comment: That almost seems like it would be 215||10k||10k. What you said make sense but I'm still having trouble reconciling it

Comment: This is a differential input and the purpose of the differential resistance is to figure out how hard the differential driver has to drive the differential resistance, and the differential driver drives its signal pins with respect to each other, not with respect to GND. The differential signal passes from one input through 215||20K and back to the other input. The current flows through one 10K, then the other 10K which makes 20K, not 10K||10K.